# MSSQL SELECT faster in filled than in empty table

Tags: java, sql-server, select, insert

In my project (in JAVA) I have to select some data from db. If data not exist I'm inserting it and selecting it again. I did two tests:

1.SELECT-INSERT-SELECT data (150 000 rows) from empty table. 
2.SELECT-INSERT-SELECT data (150 000 rows) from table filled with 5 milion trash (unused) rows.

And in results I saw that 2nd case was 15% to 25% faster.
Does anybody can explain why?

Comment: I think this is the disk cache. Try to execute `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;` and сheck your measurements again.

Answer (score 0):

How many times did you run this test?

I am assuming that 1) could be slower due to table growth.

You can monitor thsi using Using sp_spaceused

see 
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2794/report-to-capture-table-growth-statistics-for-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Are you querying the same table or two different tables in the above two cases?

If they are different tables, I suspect the second table has column indexing while the first doesn't.